# Postgres group data by non gaps

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to group some data by dates that do not have gaps

I am also actually trying to build this as a view.

```
identifier start_date     end_date
4EF        2021-07-29     2021-08-05
4EF        2021-08-06     2021-08-09    
4EF        2021-10-07     2021-10-12    
4EF        2021-10-13     2021-11-12    
2AB        2021-01-01     2021-06-20    
2AB        2021-06-22     2021-12-01
```

The desired result of the above would be:

```
identifier start_date     end_date
4EF        2021-07-29     2021-08-09
4EF        2021-10-07     2021-11-12    
2AB        2021-01-01     2021-06-20    
2AB        2021-06-22     2021-12-01
```

What would be the most efficient way to do this?

Comment: Hardest SQL question I've seen in months!  Good one +1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is fairly tricky problem, because it is a gaps and islands problem, but your initial data set is far removed from having clear values for the gaps or islands.  Here is one approach:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, CASE WHEN start_date - LAG(end_date) OVER (PARTITION BY identifier
                                                         ORDER BY start_date) = 1
                   THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS label
    FROM yourTable
),
cte2 AS (
    SELECT *, SUM(label) OVER (PARTITION BY identifier ORDER BY start_date) AS grp
    FROM cte
)

SELECT
    identifier,
    MIN(start_date) AS start_date,
    MAX(end_date) AS end_date
FROM cte2
GROUP BY
    identifier,
    grp
ORDER BY
    identifier,
    MIN(start_date);
```

### Demo

The logic of the first CTE is to assign a 0 or 1 depending on whether the previous record for a given identifier were part of the same continuous date range or not.  Once we have these 0s and 1s assigned, then we can take a rolling sum within each identifier to come up with a group number.  The point here is that we generate a pseudo group for each identifier *and* continuous dates.